# Discord.py: Embed author returning embed.Empty on edit

Tags: python, discord, embed, discord.py

when working on my edit embed command, I came across an issue. Everything works as intended except for the author. When editing the author of the embed, if in the original it is empty, after editing the bot fills it with 'embed.Empty' instead of just leaving it empty. However, if in the original the author has a value, the bot does not change it, like intended. I've attached an image so you can see what I mean too.

[image: Here you can see where the bot puts 'embed.Empty' in the author field.]

```py
  @embed.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_permissions = True) 
  @commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_permissions = True)
  async def edit(self, ctx, msgID: discord.Message):
    await ctx.send('What part of the embed would you like to edit? The `title`, `body`, `footer`, `color`, `image`, `thumbnail`, `author name`, or `author icon`?')

    og_embed = msgID.embeds[0]
    og_embed_footer = msgID.embeds[0].footer
    og_embed_image = msgID.embeds[0].image
    og_embed_thumbnail = msgID.embeds[0].thumbnail
    og_embed_author = msgID.embeds[0].author

    def check(m):
      return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author

    while True:
        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)

            if str(msg.content) == 'title':
              await ctx.send('What should the new title of the embed be?')
              new_title_input = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)
              new_embed=discord.Embed(title=new_title_input.content, description=og_embed.description, color=og_embed.color)
              new_embed.set_footer(text=og_embed_footer.name)
              new_embed.set_image(url=og_embed_image.url)
              new_embed.set_thumbnail(url=og_embed_thumbnail.url)
              new_embed.set_author(name=og_embed_author.name, icon_url=og_embed_author.icon_url)
              await msgID.edit(content=None, embed=new_embed)

            elif str(msg.content) == 'body':
              await ctx.send('You chose to edit the body.')

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return
```

I don't know why this is happening, and no errors are put out.

Comment: Why not just use an if statement to check if the author field is empty?

Comment: I tried that using, `if og_embed_author != None or 'Embed.Empty':` but still got the same issue. It seems this is happening now with the footer as well, but in the opposite way.

Comment: Adding to @NuKeFluffy comment use `\u200b` as the new value it will be just a empty line.

Comment: @Abdulaziz This worked, and I replaced `\u200b` with `\n` because that space was bothering me, thanks both of you!

Comment: Your if statement should be this: `if (og_embed_author.name != discord.Embed.Empty):`

Comment: You put 'Embed.Empty' in a string however it's a discord embed object so changing it to `discord.Embed.Empty` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Abdulaziz and NuKeFluffy, I put in some if-statements to check if the field was empty first, and leave it that way if it was (: Here is the new code:

```py
  @embed.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(manage_permissions = True) 
  @commands.bot_has_permissions(manage_permissions = True)
  async def edit(self, ctx, msgID: discord.Message):
    await ctx.send('What part of the embed would you like to edit? The `title`, `body`, `footer`, `color`, `image`, `thumbnail`, `author name`, or `author icon`?')

    og_embed = msgID.embeds[0]
    og_embed_footer = msgID.embeds[0].footer
    og_embed_image = msgID.embeds[0].image
    og_embed_thumbnail = msgID.embeds[0].thumbnail
    og_embed_author = msgID.embeds[0].author

    def check(m):
      return m.channel == ctx.channel and m.author == ctx.author

    while True:
        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)

            if str(msg.content) == 'title':
              await ctx.send('What should the new title of the embed be?')
              new_title_input = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=30.0)

              # The one being changed here
              new_embed=discord.Embed(title=new_title_input.content, description=og_embed.description, color=og_embed.color)
              
              if (og_embed_footer.text != discord.Embed.Empty):
                new_embed.set_footer(text=og_embed_footer.text)

              new_embed.set_image(url=og_embed_image.url)

              new_embed.set_thumbnail(url=og_embed_thumbnail.url)

              if (og_embed_author.name != discord.Embed.Empty):
                new_embed.set_author(name=og_embed_author.name, icon_url=og_embed_author.icon_url)

              await msgID.edit(content=None, embed=new_embed)
              return

            elif str(msg.content) == 'body':
              await ctx.send('You chose to edit the body.')

        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            return
```